# C regexec segfault

Tags: c, regex, unix, pointers, posix

This is my first real attempt with C and regex so bear with me...  I have a array of patterns (shortener_patterns) in which I pass to `compile_patterns` along with the count and array for compiled patterns (shortener_r_patterns).  I am able to compile the patterns but the code will segfault on `regexec`.  I guessing that it has something to do with how I am referencing `shortener_r_patterns` and my lack of fully understanding pointers.  Or perhaps they are not getting compiled properly in the first place.  Can someone get me going in the right direction?

```
char **shortener_patterns = '\0';

regex_t **shortener_r_patterns;

int *shortener_count = 0;


int compile_patterns(char **patterns, regex_t **r_patterns, int *count, int *compiled_count) {
    static int i;

    if (!(r_patterns = calloc(count, sizeof(regex_t)))) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        log(5, "compiling pattern %i: %s\n", i, patterns[i]);

        if (regcomp(&(r_patterns[i]), patterns[i], REG_EXTENDED|REG_NEWLINE|REG_ICASE|REG_NOSUB) != 0) {
            log(1, "invalid pattern: %s\n", patterns[i]);
            return -1;
        }
        // increment the compiled count
        (*compiled_count)++;
    }
    log(3, "finished compiling %i\n", count);

    return 0;
}

int check_shortener(char *domain) {
    static int i;

    if (!shortener_count) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (i=0; i<shortener_count; i++) {
        log(5, "checking shortner pattern '%s' against %s:%d\n", shortener_patterns[i], domain, i);
        if (regexec(&(shortener_r_patterns[i]), domain, 0, 0, 0) == 0) {
            log(1, "pattern %i '%s' found in %s\n", i, shortener_patterns[i], domain);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is where I am scanning a file to get the contents for my patterns, adding to array and then finally compiling the array of patterns.

-- snip --

```
   while ((rc = fscanf(f, "%254[^\n]", buf)) > 0) {
        if (buf[0] == '#') {
            fscanf(f, "\n");
            continue;
        }
        newshortener = realloc(shortener_patterns, sizeof(char *) *(count+1));
        if (newshortener) {
            shortener_patterns = newshortener;
        }
        else {
            log(0, "could not realloc memory for shortener patterns\n");
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
        }
        shortener_patterns[count++] = strdup(buf);
        fscanf(f, "\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    if (compile_patterns(shortener_patterns, shortener_r_patterns, count, &shortener_count) > 0) {
        log(0, "Failed to compile %s patterns\n", sfile);
    }
```

-- snip --

Comment: the code you posted throws an astonishing number of `passing argument X of ‘Y’ from incompatible pointer type` warnings. make it build correctly with `-Wall -Werror` first (or whatever equivalent for your compiler), there's just too much stuff wrong with it right now.

Comment: "This is my first real attempt with C and regex so bare with me." Just imo, I'd say that depends upon your gender.

Comment: @Pete Wilson -- Ha, nice grab... typo.

Comment: Could you ask the debugger *where* the code is throwing the segfault? Also, I've added some tags including [unix] because your using posix regular expressions. If that's wrong please change it.

Comment: It segfaults here: 
`if (regexec(&(shortener_r_patterns[i]), domain, 0, 0, 0) == 0) {`

Answer (score 1):

`shortener_count` does not have any space, you have defined it as an `int *` then set the pointer to 0, then you access the pointer.